# is O(log n) the best run time in all cases?

Tags: logging, time-complexity, big-o

i'm looking at time complexity; and i want to ask, is O(log n) the best run time when comparing to O(n log n), O(n) and O(n square)? and if so, why?

Comment: Are there any positive integer values of `n` where `log n` is larger than those other ones?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare Big O Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11940730/11683)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do you use Big-O complexity evaluation in the 'real world'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1248509/11683)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Slowest Computational Complexity (Big-O)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16388759/11683)

Comment: For small enough `n`, big O has nothing to do with the actual runtime.

Answer (score 0):

When you talk about time complexity you have to consider the fact that everything is considered for n→ + ∞. Therefore if you look at the graph of the functions you mentioned 
[image]

you can clearly see that as x (= n) increases, the time (y axis) grows a lot of slower for log(x) respect to the other functions.